# Show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then so is $\bar{H}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

This is problem 4.14 in Armstrong's Basic topology:

> Let $G$ be a topological group. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, show that its closure $\bar{H}$ is also a subgroup, and that if $H$ is normal then $\bar{H}$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Define $L: G \times G \rightarrow G:$ by $L(x,y) = xy^{-1}$

$L$ is continous $\Rightarrow L^{-1}(\bar{H})$ is closed

$H$ is a subgroup $\Rightarrow H \times H \subseteq L^{-1}(\bar{H})$ 
and $\overline{H \times H} \subseteq L^{-1}(\bar{H})$

As $\overline{H \times H} = \bar{H} \times \bar{H}$ it follows that $L(\bar{H} \times \bar{H}) \subseteq \bar{H}$

Hence, $\bar{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$

I am not sure how to continue from here. A hint would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with converging nets.

Here's the hint for normality. For the subgroup properties it's similar.

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in \bar{H}$; then there is a net $(h_\delta)$ in $H$ converging to $h$; since
$$
gh_\delta g^{-1}\in H
$$
the limit of this net is also in $\bar{H}$. But since multiplication is continuous, the limit is $ghg^{-1}$.

Comment: I havent heard of converging nets before. But after doing some googling - mostly about normal subgroups - it seems like i should define $L: G \times G \rightarrow G:$ by $L(x,y) = xyx^{-1}$ and work with that. Which at least is a little similar to what you are doing. Our book says almost nothing about normal groups or subgroups, which is a shame...

Comment: @JKnecht Nets are a generalization of sequences. You find them in many book on general topology.

Comment: Not in Armstrong's Basic topology unfortunately. But i will definitely get a better book so i can read about nets.